Эстетически не восприимчивый — слитно или раздельно?
Эстетически не восприимчивый — тоже человек несчастный.

Эстетически - лишнее слово. Невосприимчивый - тоже человек несчастный. Как видно невосприимчивый соответствует человек, то есть подлежащему, а не сказуемому "несчастный", поэтому слитно. Если бы было "он не восприимчивый - тоже человек несчастный" - он - подлежащее, не восприимчивый было бы сказуемое и писалось бы раздельно.

Правильно: ЭстетИчески не восприимчивый — тоже человек несчастный.
Пояснение
Здесь подчеркнутое отрицание. Проверяется по контексту, но в данном случае структура предложения характерна для отрицания (выделение слова логическим ударением).
Сравнить: Невосприимчивый к эстетике человЕк — тоже несчастный.
Ответы Справочной службы
Вопрос. Восприимчивый – это полное прилагательное? Тогда как пишется "не" в данном случае: невосприимчива к холоду?
Ответ. Невосприимчива следует писать слитно, если контекст не предполагает подчеркнутого отрицания признака.

А я поспорю, хотя я лайкнул)

Ссорится с соседями – тоже человек, не умеющий жить, глухой душевно.
Эстетически невосприимчивый – тоже человек несчастный. Не умеющий
понять другого человека, приписывающий ему только злые намерения,
вечно обижающийся на других – это тоже человек, обедняющий свою жизнь
и мешающий жить другим. Лихачёв.

Кстати, только сейчас заглянул.
Эстетически глухой - тоже человек.
Невосприимчивый - это название человека, а эстетический просто эпитет. То есть тут прилагательное в роли существительного практически. Кто несчастный? - невосприимчивый, глухой, человек. Ну и отрицания нет во второй части, если бы было "не восприимчивый - не человек", тогда да.
Ещё интересно, что "не умеющий жить", "не умеющий понять" - раздельно. Потому что выражение "умеющий жить", "умеющий понять", "не" относится к выражению, а не к слову умеющий. Может так?
Не восприимчивый к холоду - в прорубь ныряет.
Тут соответствие глаголу ныряет, поэтому будет раздельно?

А я тоже поспорю, ага! У Лихачева: Ссорится с соседями – тоже человек, не умеющий жить, глухой душевно. Эстетически невосприИмчивый – тоже человек несчастный. // Он описывает несчастных людей ВСЯКОГО рода. У него ударение на "невосприИмчивый". // Раздельно надо писать, если ударение на первом слове: ЭстетИчески не восприимчивый.  Здесь тема – невосприимчивость ВСЯКОГО рода. Тогда нужен КОНТЕКСТ, без него никак. // Подчеркнутое отрицание – это с точки зрения семантики.

Если ударение на первом слове, какому слово соответствует вторая сторона высказывания?

Здесь важно подчеркивание с помощью логического ударения. Характерная позиция – в начале предложения. Невосприимчивые к эстЕтике, к добрУ,  к чУвствам других людей –  все они несчастные. Здесь не логического выделения.  ЭстетИчески не восприимчивые, духОвно не восприимчивые – здесь раздельное написание при подчёркивании.

Тогда зачем тире и другое утверждение? Тут с логическим ударением сложно, потому что логику вы сами как хотите поворачиваете, логика должна быть в другом, значит. Проблема в том, что "духовно не?восприимчивые" - неполноценная фраза, просто словосочетание вырванное из контекста. А тут фраза вполне самодостаточная была.

Логику как хотим поворачиваем, да? Ну если уж у нас такой разговор начался, то расскажите, какая разница между двумя формами письма: невосприимчивый и не восприимчивый? С точки зрения русского языка, а также общего языкознания? Отрицаем мы признак (частица НЕ) или утверждаем противоположный признак (приставка НЕ). Давно хотелось выяснить, какая тут разница по смыслу.  И думается мне, что без логически-интонационного подчеркивания здесь не обойтись. А вот для иностранных пользователей языка  это вообще тайна русской души, у них-то интонационной логики и вовсе нет, как нет и  смысловой интонации

Хотя вот по грамматике английский язык реагирует на отрицание и на зависимые слова: immune, impervious to aesthetics, aesthetically impervious.  An aesthetically impervious person cannot understand art.  Aesthetically not receptive, he could not understand art.

Не думаю, что второе предложение корректно, мне кажется, так не строят фразы. Но я не достаточно хорошо знаю английский, может спросить в разделе англ языка. Насчёт же ударений, как раз "худОжественно невосприимчивый", но "не восприимчивый к эстетике", если же есть существительное определяемое - человек, то скорее будет писаться слитно - невосприимчивый человек, и при слове усилении тоже будет слитное написание - "совершенное невосприимчивый к эстетике", потому что ударение на первое слово в фразе. То есть не только ударение важно, но и то, на какое слово приходится ударение.
